# javascript HTML from document.body.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I am trying to build a string of the contents of a webpage, without HTML syntax (probably replace it with a space, so words are not all conjoined) or punctuation.

so say you have the code:

```
    <body>
    <h1>Content:</h1>
    <p>paragraph 1</p>
    <p>paragraph 2</p>

    <script> alert("blah blah blah"); </script>

    This is some text<br />
    ....and some more
    </body>
```

I want to return the string:

```
    var content = "Content paragraph 1 paragraph 2 this is some text and this is some more";
```

any idea how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the W3C DOM 3 Core *textContent* property supported by some browsers, or the MS/HTML5 *innerText* property supported by other browsers (some support both). Likely the content of the script element is unwanted, so a recursive traverse of the related part of the DOM tree seems best:

```
// Get the text within an element
// Doesn't do any normalising, returns a string
// of text as found.
function getTextRecursive(element) {
  var text = [];
  var self = arguments.callee;
  var el, els = element.childNodes;

  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    el = els[i];

    // May need to add other node types here
    // Exclude script element content
    if (el.nodeType == 1 && el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'script') {
      text.push(self(el));

    // If working with XML, add nodeType 4 to get text from CDATA nodes
    } else if (el.nodeType == 3) {

      // Deal with extra whitespace and returns in text here.
      text.push(el.data);
    }
  }
  return text.join('');
}
```

Comment: I don't know, can I upvote an answer that doesn't have a jsFiddle attached? ;o) [Here's the live example](http://jsfiddle.net/JJyVe/) for those who are interested. Only thing I added was: `.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` to give the output OP wanted. I'd also note that `arguments.callee` is deprecated, and currently unavailable in "strict mode". +1

Comment: @patrick - *arguments.callee* is not deprecated in ES5 (where deprecated means marked for deletion in future editions), however its use is restricted in that it is not available in strict mode.

Comment: My understanding is that today's "strict mode" will be standard in the next version of ECMAScript. Is that not correct?

Comment: I have no idea. ES5 strict mode code will possibly not run without error in an ES 3 environment, and vice versa. I think it's a practical impossibility to **remove** ES 3 features restricted in ES 5 without a long period of deprecation first and clear statement of that intent. I haven't seen evidence of that.

Comment: Yeah, I may be wrong about that. I thought I read it in the Wiki for Harmony, but now I can't find it. Closest thing I can find is [from this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode#Paving_the_way_for_future_ECMAScript_versions) *"Future ECMAScript versions will likely introduce new syntax, and strict mode in ECMAScript 5 applies some restrictions to ease the transition...*" Suggesting that at least some features in future versions will require some enforcement of strict mode rules, but certainly does *not* suggest full deprecation of strict mode violations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `innerText` property (instead of `innerHTML`, which returns the HTML tags as well):

```
var content = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerText;
```

However, note that this will also include new lines, so if you are after exactly what you specified in your question, you would need to remove them.

Comment: To get rid of the whitespace also: `var content = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerText.replace(/\s*/g, ' ')`

Comment: Only problem would be that Firefox doesn't support innerText.

Comment: You don't need a RegEx for that, a simple split -> join will do the job more efficiently.

Comment: @patrick dw - Very good point that somehow slipped my mind. The `textContent` property can go some way to solving this. @Stoive - Your regex looks like it will add a space between every character...

Comment: @James: Yeah, I started a solution using `(document.body.textContent || document.body.innerText).replace(...`, but the `textContent` seems to give you the content of the `<script>` as well. Lost interest after that. :o)

Comment: @patrick - lol, exactly the same as me :) 1.30am here, time for bed I think!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a [striptags function in javascript](http://perfectionkills.com/category/stringstriptags/) for that and a regex to replace consecutive newlines with a single space.

Comment: -1 Everyone is too hasty to resort to regular expressions (computationally expensive) with more efficient solutions exist. The thing that "just works" isn't always the best.

Comment: If you know of a more efficient way to replace consecutive whitespace and newline characters with a single space i'm sure the OP would appreciate you providing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the replace statement below

```
var str = "..your HTML..";
var content = str.replace(/</?[a-zA-Z0-9]+>|<[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*/>|\r?\n/g," ");
```

For the HTML that you have provided above, this will give you the following string in content

```
   Content:   paragraph 1   paragraph 2    alert("blah blah blah");   This is some text  ....and some more
```